# How do I transfer all my python libraries from one machine to another

Tags: pycharm, anaconda

Not sure this is the right forum for the question. I am trying to install pycharm and anaconda in a new machine. I have another machine which has all this already setup with all libraries that I need.

Question is is there an easy way to transfer these libraries from the old machine to the new or do I need to individually reinstall all of them one at a time(numpy, pandas, matplotlib etc)

Comment: use requirement.txt file for getting the dependencies on other machine

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/managing-dependencies.html

Comment: SO is not a forum.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use pip3 to generate a requirements.txt file and use that to re-install your environment on the new machine.

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

you copy over requirements.txt to the new machine and do

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

For Anaconda: you go to the environment you want to export using `conda activate environ`, and then you can do the following

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

to have a complete list of all the packages.
Then, to reinstall this environment copy the yml file on that computer, open Anaconda and do

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

This should create the same environment with the same name and all the packages in it.